# Windows 10 log on and log off event when I wasn't active?

Tags: logoff

I'm seeing the following data for an event.

```
An account was logged off Security ID S-1-5-90-0-10
                           account name DWM-10 at 00:01:24 
                                        DWM-9  at  00:01:36
                           Security Id S-1-5-96-0-9            
                                       UMFD-9 at  00:01:36 logged off
```

Please explain what it means, especially when I did not log on?

Comment: I edited the question to make your original formatting visible. It's been likely copied from  the Windows Event log? In such a case consider adding EventIDs, Sources and such as they might provide more context. Also please review my edit whenever it suites what you meant. There are various [well known SIDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379649(v=vs.85).aspx) for Windows. This one doesn't seem to be listed.

Comment: @Seth it is indeed listed.  The last three digits are randomly generated.

Comment: Your article is a bit better on this. You're correct that you can decode it but I was actually thinking about something like -500 for the administrator account.

Answer (score 3):

> - S-1-5-96-0-9
> - S-1-5-90-0-10

Both of these users are known system accounts. In this case, `S-1-5`, belongs to NT_AUTHORITY

> A SID containing only the SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY identifier authority.

Source: [Well-Known SID Structures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980032.aspx)

> Please explain what it means, especially when I did not log on?

Nothing unusual happened.

Answer (score 2):

Accounts beginning with S-1-5-90-0 (account names DWM-x) are generated on the fly by the Desktop Window Manager component for its system services.

Accounts beginning with S-1-5-96-0 (account names UMFD-x) are generated on the fly by the User Mode Driver Framework component for its system services.

(Ordinary user accounts begin with S-1-5-21.)

The behaviour you're observing is perfectly normal.